# Access Date/Time field updates

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table of records in Access, some of the records are just 'DD/MM/YYYY', and newer records are 'DD/MM/YY hh:nn:ss'.

All the records in the old format need updating to include the time 12:00:00.

Is there a way of doing this through SQL in Access?

Comment: what is the data type of that column?

Comment: It's a Date/Type column.

Comment: As the older records don't contain any time information, I can't run a query to pick up records with times like 00:00:00.

Comment: @TomBridges You meen Date/Time column? It hase a default time of 00:00. to the best of my knowledge this field structure in Access was not modified. If by 12:00 you meen 12:00PM, you can use [DateAdd(YourDateCoiumn, 'h', 12)](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/dateadd.php) to add 12 hours. If 12:00 AM, just use the default time.

Comment: @marlan thanks for the Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Date/Time column has a default time of 00:00. To the best of my knowledge this field structure in Access was not modified. If by 12:00 you meen 12:00PM, you can use [DateAdd(YourDateColumn, 'h', 12)](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/dateadd.php) to add 12 hours. If 12:00 AM, just use the default time

Answer (score 2):

> All the records in the old format need updating to include the time
>   12:00:00.

They are already "updated". The default display in Access hides the time part of a date if it is Midnight.

To force a display to include the time part, change the Format property of the textbox where you display the values to include time like: `dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss`

Comment: This does not answer the question. This simply changes the display on the form which is not what was asked.

Comment: Sorry. In fact I noticed, but found that task so straight that you probably was looking for something less obvious.